# How to set a deadline for POST requests based on related object?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two related model like this:

```
Form:
    name
    fields
    date_deadline

FormEntry:
    form = ForeignKey(Form)
    data
```

I want to prevent adding new entry after submission deadline. I write a validation in serializer like this:

```
class FormEntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        from datetime import datetime

        form = data.get('form')

        if form.date_deadline and\
           datetime.date(datetime.today()) > form.date_deadline:
            message = 'Entries can\'t be added after submission deadline.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(message)

        return data

    class Meta:
        model = FormEntry
        fields = (
            'id', 'form', 'data',
        )
```

It works but I can't update an form entry too after submission deadline. I want to make this validation only for POST requests (means new insertions).

Also I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. Maybe I must use permissions.

How I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check either an instance exists:

```
class FormEntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        from datetime import datetime

        form = data.get('form')

        if not self.instance and form.date_deadline and\
           datetime.date(datetime.today()) > form.date_deadline:
           message = 'Entries can\'t be added after submission deadline.'
           raise serializers.ValidationError(message)

        return data

class Meta:
    model = FormEntry
    fields = (
        'id', 'form', 'data',
    )
```

If the instance doesn't exist then it's being created, otherwise updated.

Check the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#accessing-the-initial-data-and-instance).

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I'm still wondering, is the validation best way to do it?

Comment: Permissions determine whether a request should be granted or denied access, that's not the case as you're explicitly telling the user why he can't create the resource, so validation is ok.